# Correlations among rankings

Tags: correlation, ranking, independence

In my study, participants ranked their preferences for several choices. Because moving one choice up necessarily means moving one or more choices down, nearly all correlations (Pearson's r) are negative. My sense is that this also inflated the magnitudes of the coefficients.

Essentially, the variables are not independent, which, as I understand, is not a requirement for Pearson's r, but this still seems problematic.

Can I transform my variable to remove this problem? Or conduct a different type of analysis?

Comment: What are these choices? What kind of variable is it?

Comment: Am I right thinking that this is about vectors of ranks that you have for the different choices, and you're computing correlations between different choices? What is your aim? What kind of statement would you want to make from the result of the analysis? I'm not sure by the way what you mean by "inflation of magnitudes". It seems you think that they should be somehow lower, but on what basis do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, one thing you could do is to look at a reference model for random rankings where if you have $k$ choices for every person every ranking has probability $\frac{1}{k!}$. In fact it will be enough to use the probability $\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$ for each pair of rankings for any pair of choices. You could then compute by "brute force" (writing down the appropriate formulae for discrete probabilities and evaluate them) the correlation between ranks for any two choices, which will be negative. (I'm too lazy to do that myself for you. Maybe it can be found somewhere but I don't know where. Maybe there's also a more elegant way to do it than brute force, but brute force will certainly work.)

You could then interpret the correlations you get relative to this reference value rather than relative to zero, stating that any correlation is smaller (or larger) than the correlation you'd have in a non-informative random rankings model (so that in particular it can be zero or negative but still larger than the reference).

You could also set up a simple permutation test for the reference model if you need it (which could be in the literature - it's unlikely that I'm the first who has this idea).